# JPA Batch select for entities with One to Many and Many to One association

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have entities declared in following

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_a")
public class TableA extends AbstractEntity{
...
......
........
@OneToMany(
      orphanRemoval = false,
      mappedBy = "tableA",
      fetch = FetchType.LAZY
  )
  @BatchSize(size = 10000)
  private List<TableB> tabelB = new ArrayList<>();;

}
```

The second table is following :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_b")
public class TableB extends AbstractEntity{
...
......
........

 @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id")
  private TableA tableA;


  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id")
  private TableC tableC;

}
```

The third table is following which has no association as property:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_c")
public class TableC extends AbstractEntity{
...
....
.....

}
```

Now there is no batch select when I check JPA logs and all the table_c queries are single select queries when I do something like this :

```
for (TableB tableB : tableA.getTableB()) {
     // some logic 
    }
```

In logs there are batch select statements for TableB but for TableC there are single select statements .

I am missing some basic concept here , please help me identify . 
I tried adding FetchType Lazy and batch size in TableB entity class for TableC ManytoOne association but it didn't worked .

Comment: What happens if you add `@Fetch(JOIN)` to `TableB.tableC`?

Comment: @crizzis do you meant   @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) from org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch
 ?

Comment: That's right. I suspect that, while `TableB` entities are loaded in batches, Hibernate still applies the usual loading strategy for each individual instance of `TableB`, which in this case is to load the `tableC` property in a separate `SELECT`